# Count occurence of id from mysql select and combine duplicate with php (not in mysql query, distinct, grouby)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

I have some mysql results as follows:

```
   ID
  782gt
  782gt
  782gt
  997fd
```

The end goal is to have:
an array:

```
'997fd ' => "1"
'782gt' => "3"
```

Ive tried,

```
(array_count_values($row));
```

But this does not total and combine values. This is for a high load situation so I am avoiding distinct and groupby in the actual query, tempory table and so on...

Comment: Why are you saying `array_count_values()` doesn't combine and get the total count of values? It's actually what it does...

Comment: [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) takes an array as its parameter. Are you sure `$row` is an array? What does `var_dump($row);` give you?

Comment: it is an array, however is show each seperate id and with the number 1 next to them.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that this may be a high data load operation, and you are trying to avoid using `GROUP BY` in your query.  Yet, the database is really the best place to be doing this calculation.  So I recommend a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Actually, it was a 'high load' situation - which *might* not be the same thing.

Comment: @Strawberry I still say that the DB should be involved here in some way.

Comment: I would also usually, however this may present a problem in the future, this query will be polling a large database. Everyting so far has been achieved avoiding distinct and group by

Comment: @SeanAA Then maybe look into using some sort of caching.